# Contact Field Error in Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am calling the below method in after update scenario. But this is giving me an error that "Variable does not exist: Email", please help.

```
....
public static void ConEmailOnUpdate(List<Contact> UpdatedCons){
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    for(Contact conn : UpdatedCons){
        if(conn.Email != Trigger.oldMap.get(conn.id).Email){
        }
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a trigger, the SObject type for `Trigger.oldMap` (in this case `Contact`) is known and so field references compile correctly. But outside a trigger they are not: one of the downsides of the frequently given advice to move code out of triggers.

It is generally best to pass in values to the external class rather than reference `Trigger` directly. So do that or a quick fix is to add a cast:

```
if(conn.Email != ((Contact) Trigger.oldMap.get(conn.id)).Email) {
```

Answer (score 2):

As this is trigger handler and in trigger Handler we can't directly access using this approach.

You have two solutions here.

1. Pass this in variable and then use that.
2. use get to access the value

   `(string)Trigger.oldMap.get(conn.id).get('Email')`